# Hermitian operator with gaussian eigenfunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavefunction, eigenvalue, quantum-measurements

I'm struggling to find a hermitian operator whose eigenstate is a gaussian function in $|\psi(x)|^2$. How do i do this?

Just to be clear, this is in order to realistically model the wavefunction collapse when 'position' is measured, so the eigenvalue must be the mean of the gaussian

Comment: So you are not after [coherent states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_state#Quantum_mechanical_definition)?

Comment: @CosmasZachos https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/620582/ 
I'm after an answer to this question, but I think this will help me get there

Comment: It should. Coherent states are Gaussian states serving as eigenfunctions of annihilation operators.

Answer (score 3):

The ground state wavefunction of the  Harmonic oscillator is given by a gaussian function
$$\psi_0(x)=Ce^{-m\omega x^2/2\hbar}$$
The Hamiltonian of the harmonic oscillator looks like
$$\mathcal{H}=\frac{P^2}{2m}+\frac{1}{2}m\omega X^2$$
Or on a position basis
$$\mathcal{H}=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+\frac{1}{2}m\omega x^2$$

Comment: this is true but if applied to a general wavefunction, it does not produce a meaningful measurement operator

Comment: The eigenstate with $n>1$ have nodes so it's not possible for them to be Gaussian function.